# GeoServer replies HTTP Error 503

Tags: postgis, geoserver, boundless-suite

I've seen this question was asked before but I couldn't find any solution to the problem.

Since today, my GeoServer does not reply on any requests anymore, I can't even access the GeoServer UI. I didn't change any settings since the last time I used GeoServer and it worked fine then. This is the HTTP error message:

```php
HTTP ERROR: 503
SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
RequestURI=/geoserver/web
Powered by jetty://
```

Going further, access to my PostgreSQL/PostGIS Database is denied as well, telling me

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)  Is
>   the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 54321?

Has anybody experienced something similar? If lines from the log are needed, let me know which ones.

---

This is probably why it fails:

> ERROR [context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'gwcCatalogConfiguration' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/OpenGeo/OpenGeo%20Suite/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gwc-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/geowebcache-geoserver-context.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rawCatalog' while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'rawCatalog' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/OpenGeo/OpenGeo%20Suite/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/main-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Resource must be part of a store

Comment: Hi @philippe. Since it seems like you found the solution, could you please post how you fixed your problem for future readers of this question?

Comment: Hi underdark,
unfortunately I didnt find the solution yet - geoserver is still not running at all. I´ll post the solution when I found it!

Comment: The error in the initial message has happened to me twice (on 2 different computers) in two days time! I'm unable to do anything with GeoServer. I'm using GeoServer 2.2. I can't make much sense of the answer from Andrea Aime and I certainly haven't modified any GeoServer catalog configuration files by hand on the disc. Gotta be a significant bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer to my question! Thank you Andrea Aime!

> GeoServer is not starting up anymore because its configuration is
>   ruined:
>           at
>   org.geoserver.config.DefaultGeoServerLoader.loadCatalog(DefaultGeoServerLoader.java:37)
>
> Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'gwcCatalogConfiguration' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/OpenGeo/OpenGeo%20Suite/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gwc-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/geowebcache-geoserver-context.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rawCatalog' while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'rawCatalog' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/OpenGeo/OpenGeo%20Suite/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/main-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Resource must be part of a store: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Resource must be part of a store
>           at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.validate(CatalogImpl.java:368)
>           at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.add(CatalogImpl.java:354)
>           at
>   org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoader.readCatalog(GeoServerLoader.java:382)
>           at
>   org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoader.readCatalog(GeoServerLoader.java:220)
>
> As far as I can see you have a layer sitting around whose store has
>   been deleted. This should never happen, did you try to modify the on
>   disk GeoServer catalog configuration by hand? My guess is that the id
>   of the feature types/coverage in the store "cases" do not match the
>   one of the store file itself.
>
> For example, the states_shapefile store.xml has:
>
> DataStoreInfoImpl--570ae188:124761b8d78:-7fd9
>   states_shapefile   true   
>       WorkspaceInfoImpl--570ae188:124761b8d78:-7ffd
>      
>       http://www.openplans.org/topp
>       file:data/shapefiles/states.shp
>
> and the featuretype.xml contained in the states sub-directory has:
>
> FeatureTypeInfoImpl--570ae188:124761b8d78:-7fc1   ...
>   
>       DataStoreInfoImpl--570ae188:124761b8d78:-7fd9
>
> The featureType/store/id element must match the store id.
>
> Cheers Andrea

Comment: how will you know which one are not matching? having this issue right now.

Answer (score 3):

Something is strange in your postgis log: *54321* port is not the default port. The default port is *5432*. I guess a typo in your layer config inside GeoServer. You can check and edit datastore.xml file in the workspaces directory (geoserver data_dir/workspaces///datastore.xml)

You can check the disk space, XML files in the geoserver datadir (I already have a big issue last week with geoserver with all my XML config file being empty).

Hope it helps.

Y.

Comment: Hi, 
I was able to connect to PostGIS DB again. Port 54321 was set by default since I use OpenGeoSuite, know it isn´t usually but in this setup it seems the standard config.

Still, geoserver is not workin. My log starts with an error, telling me: 

`2011-08-29 14:14:20,308 ERROR [geoserver.global] - 
----------------------------------
- GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR: C:\Users\PR\.opengeo\data_dir`

Seen it? Need more log info?

Comment: Hard to say, I will check the C:\Users\PR\.opengeo\data_dir directory and xml files inside: are they empty? Directory structure seems correct? Do you have some error before this line? after? Could you post all log in http://pastebin.com/?

Comment: That "ERROR" is not an error, it is just a high priority log message that displays the location of the geoserver data directory, it is normal. Most actual errors in the startup log will be accompanied with with a java stack trace. Find one of those and then look for the root "Caused By" clause.

Comment: Hi,
the xml files aren´t empty, I checked that. I posted the log when starting geoserver [here](http://pastebin.com/JYwrSrHY)
Hope it helps...

Comment: Hi jdeolive1, 
I have several caused by clauses there... You can find them [here](http://pastebin.com/aFcZ9YJj)!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution...
No need to reinstall.
While installing, when the path for jre is asked
add the path of the jre in jdk and not the jre in java file
i.e: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre"
and not "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.4".
At least I was making this mistake.
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason to this "503" might be that you have to install GeoServer directly in C::
Probably due to company windows policies etc....

Answer (score -1):

Had been having this problem for two days. I uninstalled 64 bit version of JRE or JDK and installed 32 bit version of JRE, reinstalled GeoServer. That worked.

Answer (score -1):

Install Java JRE 32 Bit. While installing Geoserver, give the path to the 32 bit JRE rather than the 64 bit JRE. The conflict will get resolved.[image]

Comment: Hi @ajay, welcome to GIS SE! Please consider [editing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/296746/edit) your answer to include the following: (a) a link to the appropriate Java download; (b) a link to documentation, if one exists, supporting your answer. This will help future readers (and the OP) have more context.